# find closest value in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

i have 2  web page  home.aspx and  about.aspx , here  i m trying  to load about.aspx  page  table in popup box,

about.aspx page

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Uname">Chat Is Name</td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td id="UserMessage">abc</td>
  </tr>           
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="bt_Send" 
             title="Click here to Send" value="Send" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="mbox"></div>
```

**Code:**

```
$('#mbox').load('about.aspx #msg');   
$("#bt_Send").live('click', function () {               
  var a = $(this).siblings('.Uname').attr('text');
  alert(a);        
});
```

here i'm not getting  value of  that  control

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by:

```
var a = $(this).closest('table').find('.Uname').text();
```

Comment: @user631704. I had a typo. it should be `closest`

Comment: @user631704. Did you rechecked it?

Answer (score 0):

We are encouraged to no longer use `$.live`. Instead, you should be using the `$.on` method:

```
$("#mbox")
  .load("about.aspx #msg")
  .bind("click", "#bt_Send", function(){
    var a = $(this).closest("table").find(".Uname").text();
  });
```

Comment: Instead you should attach the event in the success callback of the `load` function. I was too lazy to do it myself and try get the relevant data from the OP, but I think he doesn't need delegate event at all.